# What are three example of tables written using WikiText Mark-up Language without any Additional Documentation?

Tags: mediawiki, wikitext

Suppose that we wanted to create a table on a website like [Wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org)

What source code would produce a table such as the one shown below?:

| Fruit | NonFruitVegetable |
| --- | --- |
| CucumberFruit | SpinachLeavesandStems |
| TomatoFruit | SpinachLeavesandStems |
| ZucchiniFruit | CeleryLeavesandStems |
| AppleFruit | PotatoRoot |
| OrangeFruit | OnionRoot |
|  | CarrotRoots |

A correct answer to this question would an example of valid source code for a table.

We don't want pages and pages of documentation or explanation, just working functional code.

The following code is incorrect and contains some mistakes:

```
{| class="wikitable"
  |+ Title Goes Here.
|-
  ! Fruit
  ! NonFruitVegetable
|-
  | CucumberFruit
  | TomatoFruit
  | ZucchiniFruit
  | AppleFruit
  | OrangeFruit
|-
  | SpinachLeavesandStems 
  | CeleryLeavesandStems
  | PotatoRoot
  | OnionRoot
  | CarrotRoots 
|}
```

[image: a screen capture of what the invalid code produces when rendered on wikipedia]

Answer (score 1):

As you wish:

```
{| class="wikitable"
|+ Title Goes Here.
|-
! Fruit
! NonFruitVegetable
|-
| CucumberFruit
| SpinachLeavesandStems
|-
| TomatoFruit
| SpinachLeavesandStems
|-
| ZucchiniFruit
| CeleryLeavesandStems
|-
| AppleFruit
| PotatoRoot
|-
| OrangeFruit
| OnionRoot
|-
|
| CarrotRoots
|}
```

Try it [on mediawiki.org](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ExpandTemplates?title=Special%3AExpandTemplates&wpContextTitle=&wpInput=%7B%7C+class%3D%22wikitable%22%0D%0A%7C%2B+Title+Goes+Here.%0D%0A%7C-%0D%0A%21+Fruit%0D%0A%21+NonFruitVegetable%0D%0A%7C-%0D%0A%7C+CucumberFruit%0D%0A%7C+SpinachLeavesandStems%0D%0A%7C-%0D%0A%7C+TomatoFruit%0D%0A%7C+SpinachLeavesandStems%0D%0A%7C-%0D%0A%7C+ZucchiniFruit%0D%0A%7C+CeleryLeavesandStems%0D%0A%7C-%0D%0A%7C+AppleFruit%0D%0A%7C+PotatoRoot%0D%0A%7C-%0D%0A%7C+OrangeFruit%0D%0A%7C+OnionRoot%0D%0A%7C-%0D%0A%7C%0D%0A%7C+CarrotRoots%0D%0A%7C%7D&wpEditToken=%2B%5C).

## Explanation (just skip it if you don't want to read):

| Wikitext | HTML equivalence (roughly) |
| --- | --- |
| `{|`/`|}` | `<table></table>` |
| `{| class="wikitable"` | `<table class="wikitable">` |
| `|+` | `<caption></caption>` |
| `|+ Foobar` | `<caption>Foobar</caption>` |
| `|-` | `<tr></tr>` |
| `|- class="row"` | `<tr class="row"></tr>` |
| `|` | `<td></td>` |
| `| rowspan="2"` | `<td rowspan="2"></td>` |

Reference: [Help:Tables - mediawiki.org](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables)